# Disable long press menu in text area/input UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, cordova, uiwebview, contextmenu

This seems to be one of the most frequently discussed topics here but I couldn't find a solution which actually works. I'm posting this question to share a solution which I found as well as hoping to find a better/cleaner solution

Description of situation:

- There is a UIWebview in my application
- There is text input/area in the webview
- Long pressing on the text area/input brings up a context menu with 'cut', 'copy', 'define' etc.

We need to disable this menu without disabling user input.

---

What I've tried so far
(Stuff that doesn't work) :

### Override *canPerformAction*

This solution tells us to add `canPerformAction:withSender:` to either subclass of UIWebview or in a delegate of UIWebview.

```
- (BOOL) canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
 if (action == @selector(defineSelection:))
 {
    return NO;
 }
 else if (action == @selector(translateSelection:))
 {
    return NO; 
 }
 else if (action == @selector(copy:))
 {
    return NO;
 }

return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Does not work because the `canPerformAction:` in this class is does not get called for menu items displayed. 
Since the sharedMenuController interacts with the first responder in the Responder chain, implementing canPerformAction in the container skipped select and selectAll because they had already been handled by a child menu.

### Manipulating CSS

Add the following to CSS:

```
html {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

This does work on images and hyperlinks **but not on inputs**.
:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause of the first solution not working is the subview called `UIWebBrowserView`. This seems to be the view whose canPerformAction returns true for any `action` displayed in the context menu.

Since this `UIWebBrowserView` is a private class we shouldn't try to subclass it (because it will get your app rejected).

So what we do instead is we make another method called `mightPerformAction:withSender:`, like so-

```
- (BOOL)mightPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {


NSLog(@"******Action!! %@******",NSStringFromSelector(action));


  if (action == @selector(copy:))
  {
      NSLog(@"Copy Selector");
      return NO;
  }
  else if (action == @selector(cut:))
  {
      NSLog(@"cut Selector");
      return NO;
  }
  else if (action == NSSelectorFromString(@"_define:"))
  {
      NSLog(@"define Selector");
      return NO;
  }
  else if (action == @selector(paste:))
  {
      NSLog(@"paste Selector");
      return NO;
  }
  else
  {
      return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
  }


}
```

and add another method to replace canPerformAction:withSender: with mightPerformAction:withSender:

```
- (void) replaceUIWebBrowserView: (UIView *)view
{

//Iterate through subviews recursively looking for UIWebBrowserView
for (UIView *sub in view.subviews) {
    [self replaceUIWebBrowserView:sub];
    if ([NSStringFromClass([sub class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebBrowserView"]) {
        
        Class class = sub.class;
        
        SEL originalSelector = @selector(canPerformAction:withSender:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(mightPerformAction:withSender:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self.class, swizzledSelector);
        
        //add the method mightPerformAction:withSender: to UIWebBrowserView
        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));
        //replace canPerformAction:withSender: with mightPerformAction:withSender:
        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
            
        } else {
            
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And finally call it in the viewDidLoad of the ViewController:

```
[self replaceUIWebBrowserView:self.webView];
```

Note: Add `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to your viewController then error(Method) will not shown.

Note: I am using `NSSelectorFromString` method to avoid detection of private API selectors during the review process.

Comment: it seem to work fine, thank you! did you submit your app to the store without problems?

Comment: I submitted it today, it's still in review

Comment: thanks @Shayan RC, can you please update here after the review?

Comment: If it passes review, I'll definitely update the answer. Also, instead of using the private api selector's directly, I'm using NSSelectorFromString. Hope this is enugh to bypass detection. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Just found out method_exchangeImplementations, might be a problem as well! :(

Comment: did they reject you app? :(

Comment: The app has been approved by Apple. Hurray!! =) Sorry for the delay @laucel

Comment: Great solution @Shayan RC You saved my life =) But still there is one strange thing - this call `[super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];` always returns `YES`. Is there a way to extract default presence value for menu items? Thanks.

Comment: @rubanbs I think `canPerformAction:withSender:` (or the method we replace it with) is called for every possible menu item when a long press is detected. It returns `YES` for the items which are displayed. So, you can check which `action` returns `YES`. If all the menu items return 'YES', that means all the menu items are supposed to be shown for this UIElement PS: I haven't worked on this in a while, so I might be wrong. Please double check!

Comment: @ShayanRC great solution you saved me a lot of time. And i am did small change added this line #import <objc/runtime.h> to remove the error by Method.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can hide menu:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(menuWillBeShown:) name:UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification object:nil];

...

- (void)menuWillBeShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    });
}
```

The essential trick here is `dispatch_async`.